# How to list folder permissions located on a different server

Tags: powershell, acl

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and am running into a problem.

I want to do the following:

Get list of permissions/users on a single folder on a different server than where I am running my PowerShell window from.

Current command failing:

```
Get-acl -path "\\servername\folder"
```

Error Message:

> Get-acl : Cannot find path '\\servername\folder' because it does not exist

Does this command only work on the local machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out with the way permissions/authentications are setup in my environment prevented my code from working.

Here are the steps I took to verify if I could connect to the server:

```
Test-Path \\server\folder
```

This returned "False", which is why my code was breaking. 
The work around I used was this:

```
#Step 1: remotely connect to server
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName servernamegoeshere

#Step 2: get list of permissions on folder and save to csv
get-acl E:\foldernamehere | 
select -expand access |
export-csv C:\Users\usernamegoeshere\Documents\listofperms.csv |
#Step 3: close remote connection
Exit-PSSession
```

I still had to remote into the server and copy the csv to the location I wanted because again, any copy command to another server/share in PowerShell would not work due to permission/authentication issues.

This article explains authentication/permissions a bit better than I can:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx

---

Second way to do this with less code and not having to create a remote session thanks to user Ansgar Wiechers:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer server -ScriptBlock {get-acl E:\folder | 
select -expand access } |
export-csv \\server\folder\accesslist.csv
```

With PowerShell, there are many ways to do one thing...I think this way is best/most simple! Thanks!

Comment: If you can remote into the server you should be able to use `Invoke-Command`. That should allow you to run `Get-Acl E:\foldername | select -Expand Access` on the remote host, while processing the output on the local host.

Answer (score 3):

The command works on UNC paths as well, but UNC paths are slightly different from local paths. You need an access point to enter the file system of a remote host. For SMB/CIFS access (via UNC paths) that access point is a shared folder, so you need a path `\\server\share` or `\\server\share\path\to\subfolder`.

With an admin account you could use the administrative shares (e.g. `\\server\C$\Users\Administrator`), otherwise you need to create a share first.